# How to retrieve json array elements from JSON object in Java?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

```
JSONObject firstObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(firstNamesPath));
```

I have this JSONObject, and I want to be able to access elements in the array inside of it. The object opens successfully, I just don't know how to access the array called "firstNames". It is in a file, and the object looks like this.

```
{
     "firstNames": [ 
          "Aaron",
          "Abigail",
          "Albert",
          "Bob"
     ]
}
```

Edit: I am using org.json.simple.JSONObject . If this is not recommended, I am more than willing to change it.

Comment: which library you are using? doesn't seem to be javax.json

Comment: I'm using org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Simple search on the web could have provided you an answer. for example look [this](https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to retrieve the json array value:

Assume we have a jsonString

```java
jsonString = "{\n" + "     \"firstNames\": [ \n" + "          \"Aaron\",\n" + "          \"Abigail\",\n" + "          \"Albert\",\n" + "          \"Bob\"\n" + "     ]\n" + "}";
```

(since many classes share similar names, I am using the groupId and artifactId for distinction.)

Simple cases: use generic JSONObjects and JSONArrays.

**json-simple** (which OP is using) [json-simple website](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple) :

```java
org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser jsonParser = new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONObject firstObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonString);
org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonArray = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) firstObject.get("firstNames");
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

**JSON in Java** (mentioned in [adendrata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13245633/adendrata)'s answer): [JSON-Java doc](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

```java
org.json.JSONObject secondObject = new org.json.JSONObject(jsonString);
org.json.JSONArray jsonArray2 = secondObject.getJSONArray("firstNames");
System.out.println(jsonArray2);
```

**gson**: [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

```java
com.google.gson.JsonObject thirdObject = com.google.gson.JsonParser.parseString(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println(thirdObject.get("firstNames").getAsJsonArray());
```

---

For more complicated use cases, if you'd like to define your own class, and want to deserialize JSON string to your class, then you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/):

```java
// Create your own class:
/*
public class YourOwnClass {
    private List<String> firstNames;

    public List<String> getFirstNames() {
        return firstNames;
    }
}
*/

Gson gson = new Gson();
YourOwnClass customObject1 = gson.fromJson(jsonString, YourOwnClass.class);
System.out.println(customObject1.getFirstNames());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourOwnClass customObject2 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, YourOwnClass.class);
System.out.println(customObject2.getFirstNames());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `JSONArray` to get array type of Json and looping to access each index

example:

```
    JSONArray array = firstObject.getJSONArray("firstNames");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Hello i'm " + array.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this : `com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject`, and here's the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
      <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.41</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then you can directly use the `getJSONArray` method the answer shown above.